# GE Profile refrigerator model PSSS3RGXA SS not dispensing water or ice. Makes ice into bin

Tags: water, refrigerator, ice-maker, ice

Side by side refrigerator is cold, freezes water, makes ice cubes and dumps them into the bin.  The green LEDs for door alarm, water and quick ice are on.  The LED for lock is not on.

Pressing the actuator paddle shuts down all the LEDs and no water or ice.  Holding it down the temperature settings for the refrig/freezer are displayed.  Releasing the actuator paddle the set temp settings remain on.  No water, ice, mechanical sounds at all.

Replaced the interface dispenser asm part WR55x10818 and apart from being silver colored, the same behavior occurs.  And no ice.

I can't imagine it's either the auger motor AND the dispenser solenoid since we have a problem with water and ice.

I can't imagine it's a water problem since we get ice in the bin around the auger and we've emptied it (fills up again nicely).

Are there any suggestions?

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? If so, please give a check-mark to the answer or write up your own answer explaining what you did to get it fixed and give yourself a check mark. That will help others with this kind of problem know that this has a resolution and is a good place to look for their answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have exactly the same problem with my Kenmore side-by-side (made by Whirlpool). I don't know who makes the GE Profile, but the problem with my Whirlpool was the bundle of wires that runs into the freezer door from the bottom. The service guy told me the problem is common, and can only be repaired by replacing the entire door, which would cost - at a minimum - $500. The wire gauge was too small, and regular use of the door eventually breaks the wires. The problem has since been fixed, so I'm biting the bullet and bought a new one that will be delivered tomorrow. It makes more sense than dropping $500 into a five-year-old fridge.

Comment: The fact that passing the actuator pale shuts off the LEDs in the OPs case means this is almost certainly the problem: a short or break in the White bundle. It is a very common failure of in door dispensors.

Answer (score 0):

Have you removed all of the tape that the refrigerator shipped with?  All of it?  For sure?

Check for any door open sensor switches that may be stuck.

Answer (score 0):

These units have a water filter that when its life is exceeded it gives you a warning then shuts the water system down. Replacing the filter should resolve your problem.